# Using Wildcards in the Where clause with LIKE - returns no results

Tags: php, sql, database, web, sql-like

EDIT somehoe the acceptabe answer was DELETED :(
The solution to the problem was to use a function like this:

```
ifnull(trees.primarycolor, '') LIKE %,
```

Start Question:
Hello Friends of the internet, Family , Colleagues and random strangers.  I have a predicament that is sure to excite the webmasters out there.

My query is as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT trees.* 
$bottom_query 
FROM trees 
INNER JOIN price 
ON trees.ID=price.treeid  
where trees.primarycolor like 
 '$primary_color'  
and trees.secondarycolor like 
 '$secondary_color'  
and trees.fallcolor like 
 '$fall_color'  
and trees.droughtresistant like 
 '$drought_resistant'  
and trees.height like 
 '$height'  
and trees.spread like 
 '$spread'  
and trees.trunkcolor like 
 '$trunk_color'  
and trees.flowering like 
 '$flowering' 
and trees.fruitproducing like 
 '$fruit_producing'  
");
```

Where the $var_name are either a string such as red or green or true or false OR the wildcard %.

The actual query printed out is as follows:

```
SELECT trees.* , price.10mm , price.20mm FROM trees INNER JOIN price ON
trees.ID=price.treeid where trees.primarycolor like '%' and trees.secondarycolor like '%'
 and trees.fallcolor like '%' and trees.droughtresistant like '%' and trees.height like
 '%' and trees.spread like '%' and trees.trunkcolor like '%' and trees.flowering like '%'
 and trees.fruitproducing like '%'
```

***My issue is that even with all the wildcards in the WHERE CLAUSE, the query returns no results.***

I am using PHP and HTML - not sure what versions, most likely the newest possible.

I want to use the % as the * to select all that are of any type in the database.

Please help me Good people of the Internet, and glory shall be yours :D

Comment: Is it your intention to replace one or more of the like clauses with something more specific?  Otherwise you don't need the WHERE clause at all.

Comment: Hello Harvey and thank you, i shall try that.

Comment: Before the wild cards, is this returning any results?  SELECT trees.* , price.10mm , price.20mm FROM trees INNER JOIN price ON
trees.ID=price.treeid

Comment: My intent is to either have the user select ANY from a drop down box, or select one of many colors, and the variable will be either fileld with the % for the selection of ANY or the word (color) if they select otherwise.

Comment: Rachel i shall try and let you know

Comment: Rachael, YEs this does select my rows:
SELECT trees.* , price.10mm , price.20mm FROM trees INNER JOIN price ON trees.ID=price.treeid

Comment: Harvey, Using the %% still returns an empty set

Comment: You're opening yourself up for SQL injection here. What if I enter `'; DROP TABLE USERS;` or something for primary color? Try to use parameters instead...

Comment: Where will you enter this? i am using COMBO BOXES with predefined attributes to be selected by the user.  There exists no custom data entry within the page.

Comment: It can be put in a GET or POST request to your server. [Here's PHP's manual page on SQL Injection.](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Still dont get how the user can do anything to affect my query.  there is no inputs.  say again, there is no inputs.

Comment: Who gives this question a minus 1? Why would you downvote this legit question that brings into light so many aspects of php/sql????

Comment: WHO DONE DOWN VOTED THIS. UPVOTE ME BROTHERS!

Answer (score 2):

If no filters are chosen, don't use a WHERE clause at all.  This will run faster and be more efficient on the server, which you want anyways.  Keep all your queries as simple as possible to avoid load where not needed.  Only add on the WHERE clause to your query if a choice is made.  Don't use LIKE clauses that still return all the records.  Building your WHERE clause dynamically based on the inputs is the way to go.  Little more work, but way better in the long run.

Nick - http://www.meltedjoystick.com

Comment: Thank you good sir, i shall use this information to build a better , eficienter query.  Very good information to know.